# Apply Sketch Styles to all controls in SketchFlow Application

Tags: styles, sketchflow, expression-blend-4

Is there a way to globally apply the Sketch Styles to all controls within my SketchFlow application in Expression Blend 4 without having to apply the `Style="{DynamicResource Foo-Sketch}"` property to each and every control manually?

Generally spoken, I would like to make those styles defined in `SketchStyles.xaml` implicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably apply the styles implicitly like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource Button-Sketch}" TargetType="Button"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

You would have to do this for each control type you want to use an implicit style for.